# ffmpeg image overlay and scaling

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, scale

I use ffmpeg for overlay one image by another. 
Command:

```
ffmpeg -i bg.jpeg -i banana.png -filter_complex [1]scale=100:100[w];[0][w]overlay=5:H-h-5 out.png
```

it scaling only top image

How I can scale both images: background and top ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i bg.jpeg -i banana.png -filter_complex [0]scale=W:H[b];[1]scale=W:H[w];[b][w]overlay=5:H-h-5[v] -map "[v]" out.png
```

Comment: Wow, great! 
I begin to understand how to write complex filters:)